# how to solve ? x and y must have same first dimension

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier  
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = pd.read_csv("vitalsign_test.csv")
clm_list = []
for column in r.columns:
    clm_list.append(column)
X = r[clm_list[1:len(clm_list)-1]].values
y = r[clm_list[len(clm_list)-1]].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split (X,y, test_size = 0.3, random_state=4)


k_range = range(1,25)
scores = []
for k in k_range:
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = k)
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
scores.append(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))

plt.plot(k_range,scores)
plt.xlabel('value of k for clf')
plt.ylabel('testing accuracy')
```

reponse that I am getting is

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

my feature and response shape is:

```
y.shape
Out[60]: (500,)

X.shape
Out[61]: (500, 6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your `X` and `y`, it is about `x` and `y` arguments to **plot**, since your `scores` has one element, and `k_range` has 25. The error is incorrect indentation:

```
for k in k_range:
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = k)
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
scores.append(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
```

should be

```
for k in k_range:
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = k)
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    scores.append(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
```

Comment: it is working. i am new in python and learning. thank you a lot